# What kind of instance creation is this: new { id=item.Id }?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Index.cshtml file I have this line of code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id })
```

I know what it does: when clicked on, it directs the user to the Edit method with passing id to the method, which looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        GadgetModel gadget = context.Gadgets.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);

        return View("GadgetForm", gadget);
    }
```

I know the id value is passed to the method through " new { id=item.Id } ", my question is: when we want to create a new instance of some class or type, we usually include the the class name after the "new" keyword, like " new Person { id = 01; name = "Jim";}" , but how come this line of code doesn't have that? And essentially, I would like to know how is the value passed to the method when clicking on the button. I'm very new to ASP.Net MVC, so please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Anonymous Type.

Check this documentation: [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types)

Basically it is a way to create an object with readonly properties.

The compiler will generate an actual type but the name of the type is not known in the source code.

It is more of a convenient way to work with a group of properties in a limited scope.

As for how this gets passed to the Action in the Controller what happens is that the anonymous type gets "translated" to Query String Parameters by the Html.ActionLink function.

This means it will become the part of the url that comes after the "?" like this:

http://localhost/somecontroller/someaction?id=123

So if you had more "properties" they will become "propertyName=propertyValue" pairs in the Query String.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped a lot.

Comment: @ZiqiangXu if my answer clear up your question can you please mark as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, So when we use @Html methods and we want to use a query string, will Anonymous types always be involved? I'm asking this because I just saw this line of code: @Html.Label("Welcome to Razor", new { style = "font-size : 24px; color : red" }). As you can tell, it just turns the label to 24px and red, so apparently this new{... ...} here creates a query string. I was just wondering about what was going on behind the scene, like in the previous example the string was sent to the URL and got parsed into a query, where was this string sent to and how did it make the change? - Thank you.

Comment: @ZiqiangXu yes it is a common pattern.